# How to get only numbers as a response in python?

Tags: python, exception

I'm very new to python, in fact, to programming in general. I'm trying to do a program that compares three numbers and determines which one is smaller. I got the code done, but now i need to make it only accept numbers, and still running when it finds a literal value. For example, code will be ok if you put any number, but when you type a string value it crashes. here is the code

```
num1=0;
num2=0;
num3=0;

num1=int((raw_input("Type below the first number \n")));
num2=int((raw_input("Type below the second number\n")));
num3=int((raw_input("Type below the third number \n")));

if (num1<num2) and (num1<num3):
    print "%i is the smallest number of all three"% num1;
elif (num2<num1) and (num2<num3):
    print "%i is the smallest number of all three"% num2;
elif (num3<num2) and (num3<num1):
    print "%i is the smallest number of all three"% num3;
elif (num1==num2) or (num1==num3) or (num2==num3):
    print "Two equal numbers have been written.";
```

Comment: you can remove all your parenthesis except the outermost after `int`, and after raw_input..

Comment: You have to catch that exception and retry until the user provided a number.

Comment: Solved, thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple while loop. You may put this in a function.

```
while True:
    try:
        num1=int((raw_input("Type below the first number \n")))
        break
    except ValueError:      # catch the *specific* exception 
        print("Enter numbers only")
```

Read more on exceptions:
[Handling Exceptions in Python](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwixhdzmlcbNAhWEQpQKHRXqA9UQFggsMAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwiki.python.org%2Fmoin%2FHandlingExceptions&usg=AFQjCNF2q5_2XGEoWR5c2RzavOivTrimjQ&sig2=FYFPqucNmYPqNn0He1U_nw)

Comment: move the `break` before the `except` and remove the `continue`

Comment: Great! it worked. So "try" returns a boolean value? so when it's true it breaks? i read the link but i still kinda confused

Comment: No `try` does not return anything; it's a programming construct, which assists you to handle any exceptions that occur in a block of code, elegantly. So, when an exception occurs, it passes control to the except block. Google up and read in detail :)
Also, if you are satisfied with the answer do "accept" it, by clicking the `tick` mark near the answer!

Answer (score 1):

The most important point is probably to separate concerns, ie. keeping user input separate from validation.  You've gotten a couple of good solutions using exceptions. Here is a solution that manually validates the input:

```
def is_int(strval):
    """A string represents an int if all characters are digits.
       Returns True if strval represents a valid int, otherwise False.
    """
    for ch in strval:
        if not ch.isdigit():   # if '0' <= ch <= '9':
            return False
    return True

def read_int(prompt='Type number: '):
    """Read one integer from user.
    """
    while True:
        val = raw_input(prompt)
        if is_int(val):
            return int(val, 10)  # the 10 is the radix (base)
        else:
            print 'That is not a number.., try again'

numbers = []
for pos in 'first', 'second', 'third':
    numbers.append(read_int('Type %s number: ' % pos))
```

to use the exception handling code, all you have to do is change `is_int`:

```
def is_int(strval):
    try:
        int(strval, 10)
    except ValueError:
        # int() raised an exception, so strval is not an int
        return False
    else:
        # int() didn't raise an exception, so it is an int
        return True
```

it is also possible to be a bit more concise when finding the smallest:

```
def smallest(a, b, c):
    if b > a < c:  # if a is less than both b and c..
        return a
    if a > b < c:
        return b
    if a > c < b:
        return c
    return "Error: two of the numbers must be equal!"
```

you can call it like so:

```
smallest(numbers[0], numbers[1], numbers[2])
```

but Python has a shorthand that does exactly that which looks like:

```
smallest(*numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def getNumber(i):
    try:
        num = int(raw_input("type in number %s : " %i))
        return num
    except Exception as e:
        print('This is not a valid number')
        return getNumber(i)

numbers = []
for i in range(1,4):
    numbers.append(getNumber(i))

print(numbers)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can simply add the input getting code in try except block and handle the `ValueError` exception with some meaningful code.

```
try:
    num1=int((raw_input("Type below the first number \n")));
    num2=int((raw_input("Type below the second number\n")));
    num3=int((raw_input("Type below the third number \n")));
except ValueError:
    print "Please enter integer only."
    exit(-1)
```